# Run interference with TensorRT

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, tensorrt

Im pretty new to using AI models, and I have to run interference on my camera stream using TensorRT, to find faces. I have figured out how to build a .engine file from my .onnx file, but once i load my .engine file i can't seem to get the program to run interference. I have followed the documentation provided by nvidia, but there are a few things they are more than vague about. Therefore I hope somebody can help me get it working. Im working in C++, and the documentation i have read comes from this link: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/developer-guide/index.html#c_topics
I have read under the section for the C++ API.

I have witten the following code in the format my employer wants. I build the engine and save it if it isnt build allready, and then i initialize the engine. This is done in the method below:

```
void FaceFilter::init()
{
    m_enginepath = ProgramPath::getProgramPath() + "/resources/Engines/FaceFilter.engine";
    if(!boost::filesystem::exists(m_enginepath)){
        m_onnxpath = ProgramPath::getModelPath() + "/LLRData1/llr_models/archive/faces_grey.onnx";
        m_builder = nvinfer1::createInferBuilder(gLogger);
        m_builder->setMaxBatchSize(1);
        m_network = m_builder->createNetworkV2(1U << static_cast<uint32_t>(nvinfer1::NetworkDefinitionCreationFlag::kEXPLICIT_BATCH));
        m_parser = nvonnxparser::createParser(*m_network, gLogger);
        if(!(m_parser->parseFromFile(m_onnxpath.c_str(), static_cast<uint32_t>(nvinfer1::ILogger::Severity::kWARNING)))){
            for(int i = 0; i < m_parser->getNbErrors(); ++i){
                std::cout << m_parser->getError(i)->desc() << std::endl;
            }
            throw std::runtime_error("Could not parse onnx model from file");
        }
        m_config = m_builder->createBuilderConfig();
        m_config->setMemoryPoolLimit(nvinfer1::MemoryPoolType::kWORKSPACE, 1U << 20);
        //m_config->setMaxWorkspaceSize(1<<25);
        //m_config->setFlag(nvinfer1::BuilderFlag::kFP16);
        std::cout << "Building engine, don't stop the program!" << std::endl; 
        m_serialized_engine = m_builder->buildSerializedNetwork(*m_network, *m_config);
        delete m_parser;
        delete m_network;
        delete m_config;
        delete m_builder;
        std::ofstream p(m_enginepath, std::ios::binary);
        p.write((const char*)m_serialized_engine->data(), m_serialized_engine->size());
        p.close();
        std::cout << "\033[1;32mFace engine build and saved!\033[0m" << std::endl;
        delete m_serialized_engine;
    }
    std::cout<<this->name()<< "- init"<<std::endl;

    m_runtime = nvinfer1::createInferRuntime(gLogger);
    std::ifstream p(m_enginepath, std::ios::binary);
    std::stringstream planBuff;
    planBuff << p.rdbuf();
    std::string s_engine = planBuff.str();
    p.close();
    m_engine = m_runtime->deserializeCudaEngine((void*)s_engine.data(), s_engine.size());
    m_context = m_engine->createExecutionContext();
}
```

After I have initialized what is needed I then call the next method to start running the interference on the frames I get. The frames I have are float* array's. The following code is what is supposed to run the interference and return four coordinates of a boundingbox the face is within. I can't get it to work. 3 of the 4 values are constant for some reason and the first of the 4 values return a number constantly iterating up.

```
std::variant<PCLRGBFrame, std::pair<PCLRGBFrame, PCLRGBFrame>> FaceFilter::process(PCLRGBFrame& frame, std::optional<PCLRGBFrame> secondFrame)
{
    void* outputBuf[4 * sizeof(int)];
    std::string INPUT_NAME = "input";
    std::string OUTPUT_NAME = "output";
    
    m_context->setTensorAddress(INPUT_NAME.c_str(), frame.ToFframe.amplitudeData);
    m_context->setTensorAddress(OUTPUT_NAME.c_str(), outputBuf);
    m_context->enqueueV3(m_stream);
    m_context->executeV2(m_stream);

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        std::cout << i << " " << ((int*)outputBuf)[i] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout<<this->name()<< "- process"<<std::endl;
    return PCLRGBFrame();
}
```